# Crystal Reports 2011 report will not show date parameter without prompting

Tags: crystal-reports

Here's another question Google seems to be unable to answer, and I'm tearing my hair out over:

How do you get a Crystal report to display a date that you passed it as a parameter without prompting you for said date whenever you run the report?

I'm passing the report a "from date" and a "to date" to retrieve all records within a specified time range.  It is getting this information fine from the stored procedure populating the table the report is attached to.  I created parameter fields on the report to store these values.

However, every time I try to put these parameter fields onto the report, so I can make sure whenever its printed whomever did the printing knows what date range was selected on the printout they're looking at, the report starts prompting for a date every time its run, even though the stored procedure is passing it the date.  I even tried using fromdate and todate formula fields to receive the dates from their respective parameter fields and then put both formula fields onto the report.  Same result:  the report prompts for a date value that it should already have.

How do I make it stop doing this?

Comment: Please convert the date parameter in to string using string convert funcation then display with the textbox on the header.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what I usually use in my reports. As you can see my parameter is a range parameter, so in your case you will have to alter it slightly. The formula you create would include this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords ;
DateVar date1;
DateVar date2;
date1:=Minimum ({?daterange});
date2:=Maximum ({?daterange});
"Report For Period: " + totext(date1) + " To " + totext(date2)
```

In your case you can just assign "from date" to date1 and "to date" to date2.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field as:

```
WhilePrintingRecords ;
 "From " + totext(Minimum ({vw_periodewisePunch.tDate}),"dd-MM-yyyy") + " To " + totext(Maximum ({vw_periodewisePunch.tDate}),"dd-MM-yyyy")
```

*tDate* is date field in the report.

No Parameter Field is required.

[Result will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihXxn.jpg)